# On the identity of personalities

Tags: sahaba, people

Can someone help determine the identity of the following personalities?....

1. Abu Ishaq al-Qarshi
2. Abu Harb Hilali

Who were they? Were they among the companions or the successors?

Comment: Do you have any further useful hint? (i.e.  A narrator chain they are listed in)

Comment: Sorry I don't. I found them on sites quoting them from al-Bayhaqi's Shuab al-Iman

Answer (score 1):

**Abu Ishaaq al-Qorashi أبو اسحاق القرشي**

I found a link referring to Sho'ab al-Iman with a narration in which he is mentioned:

> خْبَرَنَا **أَبُو عَبْدِ اللَّهِ الْحَافِظُ** ، أَخْبَرَنِي أَبُو مُحَمَّدِ بْنُ زِيَادٍ ، نا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ إِسْحَاقَ الثَّقَفِيُّ ، قَالَ : سَمِعْتُ **أَبَا إِسْحَاقَ الْقُرَشِيَّ** ، يَقُولُ : كَانَ عِنْدَنَا رَجُلٌ بِالْمَدِينَةِ إِذَا رَأَى مُنْكَرًا لا يُمْكِنُهُ أَنْ يُغَيِّرَهُ أَتَى الْقَبْرَ ، فَقَالَ : أَيَا قَبْرَ النَّبِيِّ وَصَاحِبَيْهِ أَلا يَا غَوْثَنَا لَوْ تَعْلَمُونَا "
> ([Source](http://hadith.islam-db.com/single-book/682/%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%8A%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%87%D9%82%D9%8A/335567/3869))

This narrative mentions that people used to go to the grave of the prophet to complain about misdeeds they've witnessed. Note that this was not regarded as tawassul by scholars.

Abu 'Abdillah al-Hafidh أبو عبد اللّه الحافظ is referring to al-Bayhaqi's teacher al-Hakim from Nishapure.
This hadith was sadly not commented by al-Bayhaqi.
Therefore none could confirm the following nor deny it:

Some scholars mention among the du'afaa' and al-Bukhari regarded him as Munkar (rejected) an abu Ishaaq al-Qorashi أبو اسحاق القرشي which is identified as Muhammad ibn Kathir abu Ishaaqa al-Qorashi from al-Kufa مُحَمد بْن كثير أَبُو إسحاق القرشي كوفي:
This man has narrted from Layth ibn abi Sulaym [ليث بن أبي سليم](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1014&bk_no=60&flag=1) who was a younger Tabi'iy, 'Amr ibn Qays al-Mulaa'y [عَمْرو بن قيس الْملَائي](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1043&bk_no=60&flag=1) and [al-A'mash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulaiman_al-A%CA%BDmash) الْأَعْمَش who died 148 a.H.. From this we may conclude that he was a Tabi' at-Tabi'yn or among the younger Tab'iyn.
Further Muhammad ibn Ishaaq a-Thaqafy [مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ إِسْحَاقَ الثَّقَفِيُّ](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=2927&idfrom=0&idto=0&flag=1&bk_no=60&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0) who narrated above narration from him was only born 216 a.H. according to a-Dhahabi -who is certainly a trustworthy narrator even both Sahih authors didn't mention any of his narration in their Sahih books (but elsewhere). While a known and often mentioned student of him Qutaybah ibn Sa'id [قُتَيْبَةَ بْنِ سَعِيدٍ](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1940&bk_no=60&flag=1) was born 149 a.H. from whom all known authors of the era or level (tabaqah) of al-Bukhari (308 hadith and Muslim 688) have narrated from him directly except with ibn Majah who narrated by intermediate, he himself narrated from 3 different tabaqaat.
All this lead to the conclusion that abu Ishaaq al-Qorashi can't be from among the tabi'yn or Muhammad ibn Ishaaq a-Thaqafy has not met him or narrated from him by intermediate, else he must have had an age of more than 130 years when teaching this student. Imam Malik was not a Tabi'y and was born 93 a.H..

**Abu Harb al-Hilali أبو حرب الهلالي**

I found [this article](http://rohmaa.org/article/ArticleInfo/635) discussing a narrative of this man which was mentioned in Sho'ab al-Iman of al-Bayhaqi:

> أخبرنا أبو علي الروذباري نا عمرو بن محمد بن عمرو بن الحسين بن بقية املاء نا سكر الهروي نا أبو زيد الرقاشي عن محمد بن روح بن يزيد البصري حدثني **أبو حرب الهلالي** قال : حج أعرابي فلما جاء إلى باب مسجد رسول الله صلى الله عليه و سلم أناخ راحلته فعلقها ثم دخل المسجد حتى أتى القبر و وقف بحذاء وجه رسول الله صلى الله عليه و سلم فقال : السلام عليك يا رسول الله ثم سلم على أبي بكر و عمر ثم أقبل على رسول الله فقال بأبي و أنت و أمي يا رسول الله جئتك مثقلا بالذنوب و الخطايا مستشفعا بك على ربك لأنه قال في محكم كتابه
> "ولو أنهم إذ ظلموا أنفسهم جاؤوك فاستغفروا الله واستغفر لهم الرسول لوجدوا الله توابا رحيما"
> وقد جئتك بأبي وأنت وأمي مثقلا بالذنوب والخطايا أستشفع بك على ربك أن يغفر لي ذنوبي وأن تشفع فيّ. ثم أقبل في عرض الناس وهو يقول:
> يا خير من دفنت في الأرض أعظمه  ...  فطاب من طيبه الأبقاع والأكم
> نفسي الفداء لقبر أنت ساكنه ... فيه العفاف وفيه الجود والكرم

This narrative refers to:

> ... And if, when they wronged themselves, they had come to you, [O Muhammad], and asked forgiveness of Allah and the Messenger had asked forgiveness for them, they would have found Allah Accepting of repentance and Merciful. ([4:64](https://legacy.quran.com/4/64))

in a similar situation as above describing a person coming to complain his misdeeds after greeting the prophet (in his grave) and his two companions. This story should have been mentioned by imam ibn Kathir in his tafssir. (To be verified)

**To be continued**

Comment: Take your time.

Comment: Akhi have you found any verification on al-Hilali?